# HttpWebRequest collection Initializer C#

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, webrequest, system.net.httpwebrequest

When using HttpWebRequest via HttpWebRequest.Create(url) is there an easier way than the following to initialize a HttpWebRequest by using a object initializer:

```
class RequestLight
{
    public HttpWebRequest WebRequestObj;

    public RequestLight(string url)
    {
        WebRequestObj = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
    }

}
```

Now this can be used like so (desired effect of object initializer for webreq object)

```
var obj = new RequestLight("http://google.com") 
                { WebRequestObj = { CookieContainer = null } }.WebRequestObj;
```

Am I missing something? Or is this the easiest way to get the desired effect?

Note: Using the original way you have to set create the object via a static method then assign each property one by one.

Comment: You mean an object initializer, not a collection initializer. But it's not clear why you've got that `RequestLight` in the first place. Why not just have two statements? `var request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(url); request.CookieContainer = null;`

Comment: Yes, I meant object initializer. And this is for convenience (and the object initializer is much cleaner to deal with). The applications and tools built all analyze web properties so initializing a request in an optimal way is desired.

Comment: An object initializer is cleaner to deal with *if* you're in a situation where you have to do it in a single expression. But if it's a plain local variable, I'd say that the syntax you've got is significantly *less* convenient than just two statements. The suggestion in my answer is a little less obscure, I think (and more general) but I'd probably still use two statements in most cases.

Comment: @JonSkeet It's more of a pattern thing. When the object is initialized it's expected across the code base + best practice that all the properties have been worked out. When the object is init., it is then configured and the request will even be made in that same line also. 

It makes it easier to manage versus each dev making a web request object then sometime thereafter configuring it, then sometime thereafter making the call. With Obj. Ini. when the site rejects your request you don't have to follow the web request object trail that a dev has going on, it's configured & sent in 1 place.

Comment: I should also add, there's only 1 property being assigned in the example, but typically there's more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for a way to initialize the request in a single statement - otherwise just using two statements is simpler.

There's a reasonably simple alternative to this, using a lambda expression - although it's pretty nasty...

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static T Initialize<T>(this T value, Action<T> initializer) where T : class
    {
        initializer(value);
        return value;
    }
}
```

And call it with:

```
var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(uri)
    .Initialize(x => x.CookieContainer = null);
```

Or for multiple properties:

```
var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(uri).Initialize(x => {
    x.CookieContainer = null;
    x.Date = DateTime.UtcNow;
});
```